# How do you calculate div and mod of floating point numbers?

Tags: perl, math, floating-point, division, modulo

In Perl, the `%` operator seems to assume integers. For instance:

```
sub foo {
    my $n1 = shift;
    my $n2 = shift;
    print "perl's mod=" . $n1 % $n2, "\n";
    my $res = $n1 / $n2;
    my $t = int($res);
    print "my div=$t", "\n";
    $res = $res - $t;
    $res = $res * $n2;
    print "my mod=" . $res . "\n\n";
}   

foo( 3044.952963, 7.1 );
foo( 3044.952963, -7.1 );
foo( -3044.952963, 7.1 );
foo( -3044.952963, -7.1 );
```

gives

```
perl's mod=6
my div=428
my mod=6.15296300000033

perl's mod=-1
my div=-428
my mod=6.15296300000033

perl's mod=1
my div=-428
my mod=-6.15296300000033

perl's mod=-6
my div=428
my mod=-6.15296300000033
```

Now as you can see, I've come up with a "solution" already for calculating `div` and `mod`. However, what I don't understand is what effect the sign of each argument should have on the result. Wouldn't the `div` always be positive, being the number of times `n2` fits into `n1`? How's the arithmetic supposed to work in this situation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given `a = qd + r`, there is an ambiguity when calculating the remainder for negative values of `d`.

E.g.:

The expression `−42 ÷ −5`, can be expressed as either as:
`−42 = 9×(−5) + 3` or `−42 = 8×(−5) + (−2)`.

So the remainder is then either 3 or −2.

For more info: [Wikipedia:Remainder "Inequality satisfied by the remainder"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder#The_inequality_satisfied_by_the_remainder)

Also, the output in case of negative numbers in mod / div is implementation dependent in software languages. See [Wikipedia: Modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) (look at the table on right)

Comment: For the mathematical background, see [modular arithmetic](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~erowland/modulararithmetic.html) and/or [abstract (or elementary) algebra](http://www.millersville.edu/~bikenaga/abstract-algebra-1/modular-arithmetic/modular-arithmetic.html).

Answer (score 17):

The title asks one question, the body another.  To answer the title question, just as in C, the % operator is an integer modulus, but there's a library routine "fmod" that's a floating point modulus.

```
use POSIX "fmod";

sub foo {
    my $n1 = shift;
    my $n2 = shift;
    print "perl's fmod=" . fmod($n1,$n2), "\n";
    my $res = $n1 / $n2;
    my $t = int($res);
    print "my div=$t", "\n";
    $res = $res - $t;
    $res = $res * $n2;
    print "my mod=" . $res . "\n\n";
}

foo( 3044.952963, 7.1 );
foo( 3044.952963, -7.1 );
foo( -3044.952963, 7.1 );
foo( -3044.952963, -7.1 );
```

gives

```
perl's fmod=6.15296300000033
my div=428
my mod=6.15296300000033

perl's fmod=6.15296300000033
my div=-428
my mod=6.15296300000033

perl's fmod=-6.15296300000033
my div=-428
my mod=-6.15296300000033

perl's fmod=-6.15296300000033
my div=428
my mod=-6.15296300000033
```

Comment: fmod, eh? I stand corrected. Thanks very much for pointing that out.

Comment: Does anyone know of an alternative such that `fmod(-23, 10)` returns `7` instead of `-3`?

Comment: just add 10 if it's less than 0?

Comment: @ysth: that's what I ended up doing, but it would be nice if there was a module somewhere that did this already so I didn't have to include too many helper functions in my code.